# Assign object in php

Tags: php

I have a Java code that makes a function that I am interested in implementing in my php project.

This code example (it is not complete because the original is longer) assigns a patient to a doctor, they are two doctor and patient objects.

I am trying to do the same in PHP but I do not know how to continue since the syntax is quite different, I leave what I have done for now.

**Code in Java.**

```
public class Doctor {

    private String name;
    private TreeSet<patient> assignedPatient;

    public Doctor(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.assignedPatient = new TreeSet<>;
    }

    public boolean assignPatien(Patient p) {
        return this.assignedPatient.add(p);
    }

    public boolean assignPatient(String name, String name2) {

        Doctor d = null;
        Patient p = null;

        Iterator itDoctor = doctor.iterator();
        Iterator itPatient = patient.iterator();

        while (itDoctor.hasNext()) {

            Doctor aux = (Doctor) itDoctor.next();
                if (aux.getName().equals(name)) {
                        d = aux;
                        break;
                        }
                    }

        while (itPatient.hasNext()) {

            Patient aux = (Patient) itPatient.next();
                if (aux.getName().equals(name2)) {
                    p = aux;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            if (d != null && p != null) {

                return d.assignPatient(p);
            } else {
                System.out.println("The patient could not be assigned");
                return false;
            }

    }
```

**Code in PHP. (I do not know how to continue from here)**

```
class Doctor {

        private $name;
        private $assignedPatient;

        public function __construct($name){

            $this->name = $name;
            $this->assignedPatient = array();
        }
}
```

Comment: what do you expect from us now? The method `asignarPaciente` whould translate like this: `$this->assignedPatient[] = $p;` And now?

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php to learn PHP syntax

Comment: And you want us to finish the whole thing for you?  That's not really what this community does.  You are encouraged to learn more about how we can help you here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Besides the java code has many errors.

Comment: `$this->assignedPatient = array();` is `$this->assignedPatient = [];` for us lazy guys (sense PHP 5.2 if I recall)  In fact there is no need to even assign that as you can do it in the `private $assignedPatient = [];` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun ...

```
<?php

class Hospital {

    public $patients = array();
    public $doctors = array();

    public function __constructor() {

    }

    public function admitPatient($p) {
        $this->patients[] = $p;
    }

    public function employDoctor($d) {
        $this->doctors[] = $d;
    }

    public function pageDoctor($n) {
        foreach($this->doctors as $d) {
            if($d->name == $n) return ($d);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function fetchPatient($n) {
        foreach($this->patients as $p) {
            if($p->name == $n) return ($p);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function assignPatient($pName, $dName) {
        $patient = $this->fetchPatient($pName);
        $doctor = $this->pageDoctor($dName);
        if($patient && $doctor) {
                $patient->doctor = $doctor;
                $doctor->patients[] = $patient;
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class Patient {
        public $name;
        public $doctor;

        public function __construct($name){
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->doctor = false;
        }
}       

class Doctor {
        public $name;
        public $patients;

        public function __construct($name){
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->patients = array();
        }
}

$hospital = new Hospital();
$doc1 = new Doctor("Mr Hyde");
$doc2 = new Doctor("Doc Jimmy");

$patient1 = new Patient("Sick Boy");
$patient2 = new Patient("John Dying");

$hospital->employDoctor($doc1);
$hospital->employDoctor($doc2);
$hospital->admitPatient($patient1);
$hospital->admitPatient($patient2);

$hospital->assignPatient("Sick Boy", "Mr Hyde");
$hospital->assignPatient("John Dying", "Doc Jimmy");

var_dump($hospital);
```

Comment: Not bad, although I'd make the `patients` and `doctor` arrays associative, with the name as the key, so you don't have to search them.

Comment: But this isn't [codereview.se]....

Comment: @Barmar I'm too busy coding an Ambulance class to take the patient to the hospital :) , good idea tho